# My class doesn not conform to protocol decodable when I try to use a delegate in SWIFT

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, decodable

Until now my class was conform to protocol decodable. But now, to display errors on users screen, I would like to use delegate protocol but when i try to use it into my class, then it's not conform to protocole decodable anymore.

this class is decodable because I use json decoder for a API response

```
class Conversion: Decodable {
    
    var delegate: DisplayErrorDelegate?
    private var allCurrencies: [String] = []
    private var lastResult: Double?
    // GET ALL DIFFERENTS CURRENCIES
        func getCurrencies(){
        var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)
        let url = "https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/symbols"
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("APIKEYSTRING", forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print(String(describing: error))
                return
            }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
            //We have data and decode it from JSON to SWIFT so we can use it
            guard let results: Result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data) else {
                print(String(describing: error))
                return
            }
            self.allCurrencies = results
                .symbols
                .keys
                .map{ element in
                    return element
                }
            print(self.allCurrencies)
        // On verifie que l'API renvoi bien des données
         print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
          semaphore.signal()
        }
        task.resume()
        semaphore.wait()
    }
```

But when i add the line

```
var delegate: DisplayErrorDelegate?
```

that call this protocol

```
protocol DisplayErrorDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {

    func presentAlert(with error: String)

}
```

then it's not decodable anymore

Is there a way to fix it or do I have to find another way to display errors ?

Comment: And in times of async/await a Semaphore to make an asynchronous task synchronous is a horrible practice.

Comment: DisplayErrorDelegate Is not Decodable. If you want an object to be decodable , it must have only decodable vars.